# Internal webcam not working on surface book 2 new ubuntu install

Tags: webcam, github

When I try to use skype it just says webcam not found.
I found a guys post that said he used this command

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build
./build
sudo make install
```

but when i try that command it just says not found.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to add a little more detail? How is the camera connected to the computer in question? Via USB? Or is it built into the laptop case? If via USB, what's the camera model and the output of `lsusb` (with the camera connected)? If internal, what's the laptop model?

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into your post facing the same issue. 
After some research and testing I found this project addressing the many issues running Ubuntu on the Surface series: 
EDITED: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/91

Please note that Ubuntu does not allow unsigned kernels to be loaded. You can sign the kernel yourself, the instructions are in the corresponding read-me file.

Regarding your question about the webcam, it is not (yet) supported. I'd suggest to "watch" the project, so you will be notified when the webcam support will be released.

Comment: Also linux-surface has moved to it's own account. There is a ticket against MS Surface cameras here https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/91

Comment: @Queenvictoria thanks for the information about the github account update. I will edit my post accordingly.