# Surface book 2 webcam supported (in 2021)?

Tags: webcam

I'm new to Ubuntu. I tried using a virtual machine using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu on my windows10 surface book 2. When I try to use my webcam, I get an error that it cannot be found.

Are there working drivers for the surfacebook 2 webcam? Seems like, according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044663/internal-webcam-not-working-on-surface-book-2-new-ubuntu-install), in 2019 this wasn't supported.

Does this mean that there's no way to get the webcam working in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried booting a live session from USB and trying the camera? Using virtualbox adds an additional layer of complication.

Comment: Why would a webcam *on the Host* be visible to a Guest? Did you do the proper pass-though setup on the Host?